# Hibernate MultiMap cannot be found while code generation

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, maven, jpa

While i'm trying generate some classes by Hibernate using existing db relation it generates some error:

```
org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap
org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap cannot be found by org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_1_5.0.1.Final-v20160331-1852-B88
org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap cannot be found   byorg.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_1_5.0.1.Final-v20160331-1852-B88
```

My maven file:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I see apache common-collections jar in Maven Dependencies and i am able to use apache's MultiMap in my code.

Comment: Maybe is there any place for system libraries where Eclipse's Hibernate Plugin looks for jars like apache-common-collections ?

Comment: Issue reported https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-1256 ... waiting zzzZZzzZZzz

Comment: It seems solved now. I have reinstalled Hibernate Tools from jboss mars repostory and magically, worked! ;)

Comment: Confirm. Worked for me. Thank's.

Comment: I am having the same issue and re-installing did not solve this for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Here is how I fixed it:
Open Edit Configuration dialog and go to Classpath tab, remove project-name (default classpath), click the button "Add Projects..." to add your project.
Then it works.

Or you can try using previous version instead of v5.1. In hibernate  perspective,  "your configuration" / Edit configuration, Change hibernate version to previous version like v4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Just to chime in: Eclipse Mars. Hibernate 5.1.0. JDK 8. As Gordon and Kevin mentioned above, changing the version of Hibernate to 4.3 in in Edit Configuration worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the hibernate version of 5.1 to 4.3 in Console Configuration file.

1. Set hibernate perspective
2. Open Hibernate configuration tab
3. Click right on your configuration
4. Select Edit configuration
5. Change Hibernate Version of 5.1 to 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Fix for me: Mars worked with Hibernate Tools plugin [v. 5.1.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r614T.png).  I just needed to click "update" after "search for updates"