# Hibernate java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, servlets

Every time I'm trying to refresh database scheme for Hibernate Reverse Engineering File I get Unhandled event loop exception:

[Hibernate Reverse Engineering File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Madq.png)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:41)
at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractOverrideRepositoryFacade.addTableFilter(AbstractOverrideRepositoryFacade.java:31)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.mapper.editors.ReverseEngineeringEditor.getLazyDatabaseSchema(ReverseEngineeringEditor.java:219)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.mapper.editors.reveng.TypeMappingFormPart$1.doRefreshTree(TypeMappingFormPart.java:57)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.TreeToTableComposite$6.widgetSelected(TreeToTableComposite.java:400)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap cannot be found by org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.v_5_1_5.0.1.Final-v20160331-1852-B88
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 37 more
```

However, I put commons-collections-3.2.2.jar and commons-collections-3.2.2-javadoc.jar as in Build Path, so in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib: [Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/959So.png)

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Having the same issue. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling plugin. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827726/hibernate-multimap-cannot-be-found-while-code-generation but answer doesnt work. It's being tracked at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HBX-1256

Answer (score 4):

I had downgraded hibernate version to 4.3 via Hibernate Console Configuration and created configuration (Hibernate Perspective - Run Hibernate - Hibernate Code Generation Configuration), and it started working.

Comment: Okay finally found that. Just right click and 'edit configuration' inside the hibernate perspective